# Flatpak error pulling runtime org.freedesktop.Platform

Tags: terminal, monodevelop, ubuntu-16.04, flatpak

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04LTS, and I'm trying to install MonoDevelop through the Flatpak package.

I am almost done, only thing missing is the runtime. When I run the following command I get an error:

```
flatpak run com.xamarin.MonoDevelop
error: runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.4 not installed
```

Then I try to install it:

```
flatpak install gnome org.freedesktop.Platform//1.4

Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.4 from gnome

Receiving delta parts: 0/9 6.1 kB/s 98.3 kB/120.1 MB 5 hours 25 minutes
Receiving delta parts: 0/9 25.1 kB/s 426.0 kB/120.1 MB 1 hours 19 minut
Receiving delta parts: 0/9 34.9 kB/s 627.5 kB/120.1 MB 57 minutes 7 sec
Receiving delta parts: 0/9 34.8 kB/s 660.3 kB/120.1 MB 57 minutes 17 se
Receiving delta parts: 0/9 48.6 kB/s 971.6 kB/120.1 MB 40 minutes 52 se
Receiving delta parts: 0/9 84.5 kB/s 1.8 MB/120.1 MB 23 minutes 20 seconds remaining

error: While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.4 from remote gnome:
Error resolving 'sdk.gnome.org': Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Sometimes it doesn't show "Receiving delta parts", it goes straight to the error.

Maybe the repository for this runtime is broken, or the server! Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was in the file /etc/resolv.conf which had the nameserver 127.0.0.1, I changed it to 8.8.8.8 so I could carry on with the runtime installation.

You can also try to run: sudo service network-manager restart

I think that will reset the 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.1.1, otherwise change it manually as I said to 8.8.8.8 and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

## Put "sudo" before all commands

### Exemples:

```sh
$ sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo sudo flatpak install
```

or

```sh
$ flathub org.gtk.Gtk3theme.deepin
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the issue in the posted question unless you know for certain that omitting `sudo` can cause the error they were experiencing?

Comment: `sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo sudo flatpak install` command works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to solve the issue:

```
flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/21.08
```

Answer (score -3):

Try running as root.
Sometimes the problem can be there.